# MSB() LSB() popcount() in numba

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, numba, built-in

I have a program that uses numba and needs to use MSB() LSB() POPCOUNT() etc
I can't seem to find any reference to these in relation to numba, how does one get these builtin function like python's bit_length() working with numba?

```
Unknown attribute 'bit_length' of type int64

File "v.py", line 116:
def msb(x):
    return int(int(x).bit_length()) - 1
    ^
```

Comment: @CryptoFool Certainly not since the main answer is not efficient in Numba: it use a cast to `float64` which is quite expensive and a `log2` function which is very expensive. The cast back to int is a bit expensive too. Overall, it should easily take at least dozens of cycles on a recent processor while a `popcount` have a throughput of 1 cycle on Intel processors and ~0.5 on AMD Zen ones (even ~0.25 on newer ones). On my Intel CoffeeLake machine, the log2 takes 40 cycles and is not accurate for big numbers. It is 40 times slower than a popcount. On AMD it should be about 100 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

Numba does not provide a `popcount` function yet. While this function can be implemented, it will definitively not be user-friendly (it required to delves into the way Numba works and deals with the LLVM-Lite JIT), not portable either (dependent of the target architecture). For more informations please read [the documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/high-level.html#implementing-intrinsics) about intrinsics and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145369/using-cpu-instruction-directly-from-numba). If you really want to take this path, then please note that while a new intrinsic function can be implemented in Numba for your needs, popcount appears not to be supported yet be the LLVM-Lite JIT wrapping layer and AFAIK the only solution is to call inline assembly directly from LLVM-Lite which is neither simple nor portable (it does not even work on all x86-64 CPUs)...

`bit_length` is a method of `int` objects that only make sense on variable-sized integers but Numba does not use such type (like Numpy) because of they very big overhead compared to native fixed-size numbers.

Numpy will [soon add a `popcount` function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16325) and this function will likely be implemented by Numba later but this is not yet the case. This is certainly the best solution for future readers.

Hopefully, there is a way to get a relatively fast code using [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) although it will certainly not produce a code as fast as instructions like `popcnt` available on most x86-64 recent processors. For example, a popcount on unsigned 32-bit integers can be implemented using the following code in Numba:

```
import numba as nb

# The signature is critical for the function to be correct
@nb.njit('int_(uint32)')
def popcount(v):
    v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555)
    v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333)
    c = np.uint32((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24
    return c

# Returns 17
popcount(0b00110101_00011110_00111010_11101001)
```

On my machine, this is very fast, especially if the above function is put in in a loop that can be automatically vectorized since the JIT can use AVX-2 SIMD instructions: it takes about ~4 cycle/int without on my machine and ~1.5 cycle/int with AVX-2.

The same thing applies for the MSB and LSB. Note that bit twiddling hacks with integers having fewer bits should results in a faster generated code (especially due to SIMD and the need for fewer instructions).

Comment: thanks. it does in fact run faster than the native version